# Open up the multiple accordion tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, accordion

I have implemented a accordion content tab. Currently it is allowing to open up a single menu at a time. I need to open the other tabs also at the same time.

Here is my code

```
(function(jQuery){
     jQuery.fn.extend({  
         accordion: function() {       
            return this.each(function() {

                var $ul = $(this);

                if($ul.data('accordiated'))
                    return false;

                $.each($ul.find('ul, li>div'), function(){
                    $(this).data('accordiated', true);
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $.each($ul.find('a'), function(){
                    $(this).click(function(e){
                        activate(this);
                        return void(0);
                    });
                });

                var active = (location.hash)?$(this).find('a[href=' + location.hash + ']')[0]:'';

                if(active){
                    activate(active, 'toggle');
                    $(active).parents().show();
                }

                function activate(el,effect){
                    $(el).parent('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').children('ul, div').slideUp('fast');
                    $(el).siblings('ul, div').slideToggle("slow");((!effect)?'fast':null);
                }

            });
        } 
    }); 
        $('ul').accordion();
             $(".info").find("a").click(function(){
              var trid = $(this).parent().attr("idcust");                
              var trdata = $(this).parent().attr("custdata");
            // Hide all content divs and show only the one related to the click
             $("#"+trid).show().children().not(trdata).hide();
            $(trdata).toggle();
        });
})(jQuery);
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RVJQN/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i want to say there is lots of junk code in the CSS & JS. Write like this:

**JS**

```
$('.accordion a').click(function(){
    $('.accordion div').slideToggle("slow");;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion div {  background: #fff;overflow:hidden;display:none;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RVJQN/1/

Comment: I don't want to open all the tabs on one click. For example if one tab  is opened, then i need to open the another tab also by clicking on respective tab

Answer (score 0):

Accordions don't support multiple open tabs (no API property to set), Check out - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion